# Split attribute elements values of attribute list in Nifi

Tags: regex, apache-nifi

Using Extract Text processor, I have been able to convert a HTML table into an attribute list 'rw' (shown in picture)
[image]

each rw.1 , rw.2, ... represents a row of a table of unknown size.

Now I want to split the attribute 'rw' which is is now represented as list/array rw.1,rw.2,rw.3 etc . The regex to split one such attribute would be

"(?:)([\s\S]*?)(?:</td>)" and lets say rw.1 would be

`<td> <a href="//money.rediff.com/companies/rainbow-denim-ltd/16070060"> Rainbow Denim Ltd. </a> </td> <td>XT</td> <td>7.50</td> <td>7.75</td> <td><FONT class="green">+ 3.33</FONT></td>`

and the output I want is :

```
{"company" : "<a href="//money.rediff.com/companies/rainbow-denim-ltd/16070060"> Rainbow Denim Ltd. </a>" , "code" : "XT", "price" : 7.75 }
```

Can somebody please help me with any processor and how to go about it

Comment: why do you need that? you already have 1000+ attributes. what are you going to do with all of them?

Comment: @daggett , I am panning to convert each record of a row into a Json equivalent record and then say publish it to  kafka or Solr. And yes the records count are dynamic in nature it can even be 2000+

Answer (score 1):

If your HTML is actually valid XHTML, you might be better off with a [SplitXml](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.5.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.SplitXml/index.html) than ExtractText. Depending on what you're trying to do, you could act on individual tags in the table, and merge them back together again with [MergeContent](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.5.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.MergeContent/index.html)/[MergeRecord](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.5.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.MergeRecord/index.html). After SplitXml, you have access to fragment.* attributes, which can help with indexing (index 1 = "company" field, e.g.).

Answer (score 0):

there is a good library to parse html: [jsoup](https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/attributes-text-html)

you can use `ExecuteGroovyScript` with custom code that uses this library.

below is just an example to parse html ( http://groovy-lang.org/ ) and extract some elements from it

```groovy
@Grab(group='org.jsoup', module='jsoup', version='1.11.2')

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;
import groovy.json.JsonBuilder;

def ff=session.get()
if(!ff)return

def rawIn = ff.read()
def doc=Jsoup.parse(rawIn, "UTF-8", '')
rawIn.close()
//search for tag article inside div
Elements articles = doc.select("div article")

articles.each{art->
    def json = [:]
    json.type = art.select('div').first().attr('class')
    if( json.type.startsWith('icon') ) {
        json.title = art.select('h1').first().text()
        json.text  = art.select('p').first().text()
        def ffOut=ff.clone(false)
        ffOut.write("UTF-8"){w-> new JsonBuilder(json).writeTo(w) }
        REL_SUCCESS << ffOut
    }
}
session.remove(ff)
```

as a result you'll have separate flow files with small json objects:

```groovy
{
    "type": "icon icon-1",
    "title": "Flat learning curve",
    "text": "Concise, readable and expressive syntax, easy to learn for Java developers"
}
{
    "type": "icon icon-2",
    "title": "Smooth Java integration",
    "text": "Seamlessly and transparently integrates and interoperates with Java and any third-party libraries"
}
...
```

that corresponds to http://groovy-lang.org/ page

probably it's not a good idea to use `Grab` inside the code - better to download library and put it into `nifi/lib` folder.

Comment: You can also use @Grab from ExecuteScript and such in NiFi 1.5.0+ (when ExecuteGroovyScript was also added and supports it as mentioned)